# Properly accumulating data from async functions in Python

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I am getting into async operations in Python and would like to use it properly, yet I found a few ways to retrieve data from multiple coroutines and am not sure which one to use.

The idea is as follows: for multiple records in a form of input-output objects, get the input, asynchronously run the API queries, gather results and update initial objects with them. Also, could you please suggest me on how to limit the tasks run concurrently to predefined value? I am afraid of spamming the server with thousands of requests at once and getting flagged because of that.

Currently I use a dict with object:asyncio.create_task pairs, wait for completion of all the tasks, then for each pair get the result and update the dicts key object.

Something along the following lines:

```py
class myobj:
  text:str=''
  result:str=''
  
  def __init__(self, text:str) -> None:
    self.text=text

items:list[myobj]=[myobj('lorem'), myobj('ipsum')]

tasks={}
for item in items:
  tasks[item] = asyncio.create_task(api_query(item.text))

await asyncio.wait(tasks.values())

for item,query in tasks.items():
  item.result = query.result()
```

It feels awkward though, as if I was doing something wrong, although it seems to work properly.

I also tried multiple variants of gathering results of multiple tasks and wondered which one (if not all) is correct. Below is my code:

```py
import asyncio
import time

async def reverse(text:str) -> str:
  await asyncio.sleep(len(text)/10)
  return text[::-1]

async def main() -> None:
  names = [
    "Rowan Adams",
    "Leo Ferrell",
    "Lottie Mccullough",
    "Lina Riggs",
    "Hope Garrett",
    "Humza Galvan",
    "Felix Carr",
    "Sam English",
    "Trinity Moyer",
    "Lennon Osborn",
    "Nicolas Chapman",
    "Bushra Bowers",
    "Izabella Banks",
    "Malik Fitzgerald",
    "Maisha Donovan",
    "Kathleen Patel",
    "Kiara Odling",
    "Abby Larsen",
    "Kye Joyce",
    "Jimmy Davidson"
  ]

  t1_s = time.perf_counter()
  results1 = await asyncio.gather(*[asyncio.create_task(reverse(name)) for name in names])
  t1_e = time.perf_counter()
  print(results1)
  print(t1_e-t1_s,'\n')

  t2_s = time.perf_counter()
  results2 = await asyncio.gather(*[reverse(name) for name in names])
  t2_e = time.perf_counter()
  print(results2)
  print(t2_e-t2_s,'\n')

  t3_s = time.perf_counter()
  tasks1 = [asyncio.create_task(reverse(name)) for name in names]
  await asyncio.wait(tasks1)
  t3_e = time.perf_counter()
  print([task.result() if task.done() is True else 'waiting' for task in tasks1])
  print(t3_e-t3_s,'\n')

  t4_s = time.perf_counter()
  tasks2 = [reverse(name) for name in names]
  results4 = await asyncio.gather(*tasks2)
  t4_e = time.perf_counter()
  print(results4)
  print(t4_e-t4_s,'\n')

  t5_s = time.perf_counter()
  tasks3 = [asyncio.create_task(reverse(name)) for name in names]
  results5 = await asyncio.gather(*tasks3)
  t5_e = time.perf_counter()
  print([task.result() for task in tasks3])
  print('-----')
  print(results5)
  print(t5_e-t5_s,'\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  asyncio.run(main())
```

From this testing I conclude that:

- asyncio.wait returns a list of tasks with their status, so it could be used to gather results from already completed tasks
- asyncio.gather returns results no matter if it was provided with coroutine or task
- when working with tasks, you can access results by running a .result() function for each completed task (ex. 3 and 5)
- I assume holding onto variables with coroutines/tasks after completion and filling result variables is pointless, but it may be reasonable to keep tasks and access results from them, instead of creating dedicated variable to store them

I have seen solutions where results from gather were zipped with the original list, I also considered using for loop like:

```
results = asyncio.gather(*[api_query(item.text) for item in items])

for i in range(0, len(items)):
  items[i].result = results[i]
```

But it seems even more cumbersome than the dict solution.

Comment: Those are two distinct questions. You should make two questions for them. As for the first issue of overwhelming the server, consider starting `N` worker tasks who feed from an `asyncio.Queue` and put their results into another queue. A regular deque or list for input may also work in this particular case

Comment: You can also use an [`asyncio.Semaphore`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore`) to rate-limit API calls specifically.

Comment: @Homer512 Thank you for your answer, I will definitely look deeper into mentioned solution. The most confusing thing to me is making bond between the async results and the objects that should be updated with them so I focused heavily on this section, missing out on the load optimizations.

Comment: I don't think there is much to say about the second part except "whatever floats your boat." Since it's more of a style question with slight performance differences that would need a specific example. For example if return values are relatively large, you may want to process them directly to improve cache efficiency and deallocate them early instead of waiting for a `gather` of all. Personally I would probably just `zip(names, list_of_tasks)` or let the tasks return a `(name, value)` pair

Comment: Good points, thank you! May I ask for your opinion on whether it is fine to keep the tasks and access the results by the appropriate function or should I save them outside of the task and drop it to minimize the overhead related with storing the task object? My current implementation (first block of code) relies on keeping the long dict with all task objects in it and then processing them in the last loop, which seems wasteful.

Comment: I don't think the task objects themselves have a large overhead once they are done computing. However, dropping them early might release memory for return value and arguments (?, not sure) which could be a factor. This seems like something that would be pretty easy to stress-test.